# Two different Query string redirect to same structure Htaccess

Tags: string, .htaccess, url-rewriting, rules

Please help me, I have two cases, I have a URL to redirect, for example

https://example.com/about-us and my rewrite rule is

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?pageName=$1 [QSA,L]
```

and it is working perfectly for all pages with query pageName.

I want to redirect a different query string to this same structure like I have URL like

```
https://example.com/index.php?filter=latest
```

and I want to redirect this to the same format like above for about us page e.g

```
https://example.com/latest
```

how it can be possible? please help me, thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can't use same format or URI pattern for two rules , you can however change your second URL format to look something like `https://example.com/second/latest` here `second` can be any word you want add in the rule's pattern

```
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^second/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?filter=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Remember to put this rule at the top or before the existing one.